# SQL Server 2005 Query, Join, Group By, Return Repeated Rows

Tags: sql-server-2005, join, group-by

I have this query in SQL Server 2005:

```
SELECT ppd.carplanpagoid,
       capital,
       interes,
       ppd.mtocuota,
       sinteres,
       scapital,
       estado,
       ppd.objprecolocacionid,
       mtopagint,
       mtopagcap,
       tasaintesperada,
       f1.descripcion AS tipocuota,
       tasaefectiva,
       plazo,
       numcuotas,
       nombre,
       numero,
       mtosolicitado,
       f2.descripcion AS moneda,
       g1.descripcion AS Oficial,
       convert(varchar(10), c.fecha, 101)AS FechaPagoCaja,
       codigoSec,
       f3.descripcion AS monedaCaja1,
       CASE
           WHEN c.objMoneda =
                  (SELECT stbcatfinid
                   FROM stbcatfin
                   WHERE codint = 'COPF') THEN c.montoMonNac
           ELSE c.montoMonExt
       END MontoCaja,
       0.00 AS SaldoInicial,
       0.00 AS SaldoPagado
FROM carcaja c
LEFT JOIN carplanpagodet ppd ON c.objCredito = ppd.objprecolocacionid
LEFT JOIN carplanpago pp ON c.objCredito = pp.objprecolocacionid
LEFT JOIN carprecolocacion pc ON c.objCredito = pc.carprecolocacionid
LEFT JOIN adqclientenew cl ON c.objcliente = cl.adqclienteid
LEFT JOIN stbcatfin f1 ON pp.objtipocuota = f1.stbcatfinid
LEFT JOIN stbcatfin f2 ON pc.objmonedapfid = f2.stbcatfinid
LEFT JOIN stbcatgrl g1 ON pc.objoficial = g1.stbcatgrlid
LEFT JOIN stbcatfin f3 ON c.objmoneda = f3.stbcatfinid
WHERE c.objTipoTransaccion = 5
  AND estado = 'P'
  AND pc.objtipocliente = 'NAT'
```

And it returns these rows (I'm not going to put all the columns):

```
carplanpagoid capital   intereses   mtocuota
-----------------------------------------------------
 9            750.00    225.00           975.00
10            750.00    225.00           975.00
 9            750.00    225.00           975.00
10            750.00    225.00           975.00
57            125.00    37.50            162.50
58            125.00    37.50            162.50
59            125.00    37.50            162.50
57            125.00    37.50            162.50
58            125.00    37.50            162.50
59            125.00    37.50            162.50
57            125.00    37.50            162.50
58            125.00    37.50            162.50
59            125.00    37.50            162.50
```

And here comes my trouble, it return repeated rows (see `carplanpagoid`), I know I need a group by clause but I don't know where put it.

Comment: Oh goodness - [**please nicely format your SQL code!**](http://sqlformat.appspot.com/)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have so much experience with sql

Comment: I **posted a link** where you can easily format your SQL code nicely - really doesn't take a rocket scientist to do so!